# Visual Studio 2017 "Find In Files" - Window does not display

Tags: visual-studio-2017, findinfiles

The "Find In Files" window appears not to display at all.  I have opened my Solution and tried selecting "Find In Files" from the Edit menu, and also using the Ctrl-Shift-F shortcut.  Nothing happens.

Answer (score 9):

In answers to related questions, it was suggested to select Window->Reset Window Panel.  Visual Studio 2017 does not have "Reset Window Panel" but rather "Reset Window Layout".  This might work.  I actually used Window->"Dock As Tabbed Document" to fix the problem of the invisible window.  It may have been there all along and just minimized.  In any case, this solution worked.

Comment: Thanks. Window->"Dock As Tabbed Document" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Window->"Dock As Tabbed Document" works, but also check that it's not on another screen.